# How to insert @media queries in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to call two different wp_bootstrap_navwalker files that I've forked:
- wp_bootstrap_navwalker-DESK.php
- wp_bootstrap_navwalker-MOBILE.php

I'd like to call the first when

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

and the second one instead when

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
```

I don't know how to create the right function to do that in functions.php!

Is it  possible to create a conditional function using media queries rules to load the right one of the following codes:

```
require_once "inc/bootstrap/wp_bootstrap_navwalker-DESK.php";
```

or

```
require_once "inc/bootstrap/wp_bootstrap_navwalker-MOBILE.php";
```

???

Any help will be really appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: Media queries are CSS. They’re interpreted client-side, whereas PHP is interpreted server-side. You can’t include a PHP file based on a CSS media query because PHP has finished by the time CSS is parsed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Any idea how can I fix it in other ways?

Comment: You can add this media query in style.css of your child theme.

Comment: @WisdmLabs Right, and how does the OP then include a _PHP script_ from a CSS file?